# how to add checked class for id of an input-tag in a other tag <label> or <p> or <a>

Tags: html, css, radio-button, styles, checked

I encountered a problem while doing the project.

why not run `#MyId:checked~#show`(style)   for `ID` of a tag in `<a>` , `<label>` and `<p>`

is there a way to run `css` for it?
without removing and moving the `label tag`
, change the  `#test:checked~#show` of this example to run properly.

```css
#show {
  display: none;
  }
#test:checked~#show {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<label>
 <input id="test" type="radio" value="0">click to show
</label>
<div id="show">
  hahahahahahha
</div>
```

Comment: your imput is inside a label, so there is no way for that in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otherwise you can do that:

```css
#show {
  display: none;
  }
#test:checked~#show {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<input id="test" type="checkbox"  >
<label for="test">click to show</label>
<div id="show">
  hahahahahahha
</div>
```